# Ruby Thread. why "#Join"?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

This may sound dumb question. but Please guide me.

https://apidock.com/ruby/Thread/join

```
a = Thread.new { print "a"; }
a.join(5)
```

As we see here, `#join` method is basically,
"Hey OS, **Run** this code block(thread), 5 seconds from now."

but where this name come from? `join` . why not just `run`?
in Java, it seems like slightly different meaning.

### EDIT

I found out that actually `#join` is blocking call. It means that check 5 second later, if the thread has been finished or not. If `finished`, *kill the thread.*(x) . join will return Thread object. which is already Dead.

Comment: _"check 5 second later [...] If finished, kill the thread"_ – note that `join` doesn't kill the thread. It merely waits for it to finish.

Answer (score 8):

Not quite. `join` is the traditional name for the operation that waits for a thread to complete. Execution "splits" when you start a thread, and "joins" when a parent becomes aware of a thread's completion.

`a.join(5)` doesn't say "run this thread 5 seconds from now", it says "wait up to 5 seconds for this thread to finish". It starts running as soon as you create it.

Comment: Thanks! I understood that the thread to be joined(finished) 5 second later. Then,  when exactly the thread `started`?

Answer (score 4):

[`Thread.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Thread.html#method-c-new) starts the thread. You can do a simple test:

```
Thread.new { puts "started" };
sleep 1
puts "done"
```

It will print `started` immediately, then wait a second, then print `done`.

Or run `Thread.new` in `irb` and see it execute immediately.

You need `a.join` because without it the main program might exit and kill the threads before the thread is complete. For example...

```
Thread.new do
  puts "start"

  # Simulate the thread doing some work
  sleep 1

  puts "end"
end
sleep 0.5
```

This will print `start` and that's it. The main program will end and kill the thread. The main process needs to wait until the thread is complete with [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Thread.html#method-i-join).

It's called ["join"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/join) because you are joining the thread back together with the main thread which spawned it.

Comment: I found something weird. at your first code block. If you remove, `sleep 1` in a code, The thread never run. why is that?

Comment: @JinLim if the main thread finishes first, all remaining threads are killed.

Comment: hmmm, the spawned thread only lives within the **block** of `Thread.new`, doesn't it? `join` just makes the main thread to wait until that child thread finishes. The official doc says _Any threads not joined will be killed when the main program exits._ But what could be the use of keeping alive threads that have not been joined? In practice, you may want the main thread to just continue and leave the child threads to "die" alone.